# Modify Neural Network to Predict on 3 examples at a time

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, tensor

I have here a convolutional neural network that takes a 96x96x3 picture and outputs a 1x128 encoding. (the undefined functions are just series' of layers)

How would I modify the architecture to take a 3x96x96x3 input and produce a 3x128 output (forward propagate 3 times with the same parameters)?

```
def faceRecoModel(input_shape):
    """
    Implementation of the Inception model used for FaceNet

    Arguments:
    input_shape -- shape of the images of the dataset

    Returns:
    model -- a Model() instance in Keras
    """

    # Define the input as a tensor with shape input_shape
    X_input = Input(input_shape)

    # Zero-Padding
    X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(X_input)

    # First Block
    X = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), name='conv1')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name='bn1')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Zero-Padding + MAXPOOL
    X = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=2)(X)

    # Second Block
    X = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), name='conv2')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=1, epsilon=0.00001, name='bn2')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Zero-Padding + MAXPOOL
    X = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(X)

    # Second Block
    X = Conv2D(192, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), name='conv3')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=1, epsilon=0.00001, name='bn3')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Zero-Padding + MAXPOOL
    X = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2)(X)

    # Inception 1: a/b/c
    X = inception_block_1a(X)
    X = inception_block_1b(X)
    X = inception_block_1c(X)

    # Inception 2: a/b
    X = inception_block_2a(X)
    X = inception_block_2b(X)

    # Inception 3: a/b
    X = inception_block_3a(X)
    X = inception_block_3b(X)

    # Top layer
    X = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), data_format='channels_first')(X)
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(128, name='dense_layer')(X)

    # L2 normalization
    X = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(X)

    # Create model instance
    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name='FaceRecoModel')

    return model
```

Comment: Models in Keras takes a **batch** of input samples, so you can feed the model as many input samples as possible.

Comment: I want the network to process images 3 at a time so dataset would be shape (m,3,96,96,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take inputs of shape `(batch_size, 3, 96, 96, 3)`, i.e. process 3 images as a single input sample, then you need to create a new model which uses your trained model and applies it on each of those 3 images independently. You can easily achieve this using [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) wrapper in Keras:

```
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

inp = Input(shape=(3, 96, 96, 3))
out = TimeDistributed(the_trained_face_rec_model)(inp)

model = Model(inp, out)
```

The output of this new model has a shape of `(batch_size, 3, 128)`. There is no need to compile or train this new model, because simply it is just a wrapper around your previously trained model. So you can use: `predictions = model.predict(my_images)`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: As mentioned by op that the network should process 3 images at a time as dataset would be shape (m,3,96,96,3), then one easy way is to create three standard inception networks in a parallel fashion and then concatenate the output received from each of them.

Comment: that would work but I would be unable to use the keras fit function, as my loss function requires all 3 outputs, and calculus is hard :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify anything, the first dimension of the input in Keras is always the batch dimension, so you literally need to feed an input of shape `(3, 96, 96, 3)` and you will get a corresponding output of `(3, 128)`. No modifications to the code are needed.